# Grouping a large number of objects via property

Tags: javascript, mongodb, postgresql, lodash

I'm trying to map a relational database, and piece together the different tables with the column id's. Say I have two tables: `cars`, `owners`. The `cars` table has an `owner_id` column. I'm trying to map over all `owners` and add a property to it `owners.cars`. One simple way is to pull all cars and then run a `groupBy` function using `lodash`. Like this.

```
cars = _.groupBy(cars, 'owner_id`)
```

However, my data-set is so large around 200,000 items, and it seems to just hang the process.

What's the best way to cycle this kind of information? The reverse would be looping over every `car` and inserting it into the correct `owner`.

This is kind of a migration from an existing relational postgres database to a nosql mongo database.

Comment: You have tables or collections?

Comment: I'm moving from Tables to Collections and mapping relational ID's.

Comment: Depending on the average size of each object at 200k objects... have you excluded memory/cpu as an issue?

Comment: @ry_donahue It hasn't been an issue yet. The process just takes about an hour. Wondering if there are better ways to do this sort of thing.